# Home Icon Up Indicator Compat Action Bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I'm trying to change the "up" indicator, I've implemented the new compat action bar and I'm not able to customize it.

I've tried adding to values-v11/styles.xml

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_action_logo_barra_de_acciones_blanco</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_style</item>
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/arrow_up_black</item>
</style>
```

and to values/styles.xml

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/action_bar_style</item>
    <item name="icon">@drawable/ic_action_logo_barra_de_acciones_blanco</item>
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/arrow_up_black</item>
</style>
```

But is still not working.

Thanks in advance, Diego.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, maybe already late, but I had same issue and solved it by defining "homeAsUpIndicator" in main theme before ActionBar style.
Here is my res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
</style>

<style name="AppTheme"  parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/messages_form_banner</item>
</style>
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Error:(6, 40) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'homeAsUpIndicator' with value '@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_holo_dark').
can you tell me what's the problem plz ? THX

Comment: @Fakher it is just example of usage, and I was using my resources. Try to link drawable from your project.